# Bind canvas width/height to custom static property?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I'm trying to get my canvas size to be a specific width/height for a static property class I have defined as follows in my `App.xaml.cs` file:

```
public class CanvasAttr
{
    public static double Width 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return Window.Current.Bounds.Width / 4;    
        } 
    }
    public static double Height 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 4;    
        } 
    }
}
```

And here's my `MainPage.xaml`

```
<Page
    x:Class="Bossanova.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Bossanova"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Height="765.015">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="DrawSurface" TargetType="Canvas">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding CanvasAttr.Width}" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding CanvasAttr.Height}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Canvas x:Name="Main" Style="{StaticResource DrawSurface}">

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

As you can see, within the `<Style>` definition, I've added `<Setter>` tags for the Width and Height properties of the canvas. The problem is that a simple `{Binding CanvasAttr.Width}` doesn't seem to affect anything. What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: Is all you want to have a Canvas that is a quarter of the window width and height? Then why not simply create a suitable Grid layout with a row and a column that each take a quarter of the available space?

Comment: @Clemens because I do not know how to do that, hence this question in the first place :). I'm all eyes though if you can demonstrate via code. Note: if you're thinking of `Width="2*"` where `2*` denotes "20% of space", I've already tried that, and believe that feature is deprecated in WinRT 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Use [x:Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) to bind to static properties in XAML -

```
<Setter Property="Width" Value="{x:Static local:CanvasAttr.Width}" />
<Setter Property="Height" Value="{x:Static local:CanvasAttr.Height}" />
```

Comment: Visual Studio tells me that `"Static" is not supported in a windows app project`. +1 for you anyway, though: this may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for that binding. Just create an appropriate Grid layout:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas x:Name="Main" Background="AliceBlue">

    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Note however that Canvas only does absolute positioning of its child elements. Hence setting the Width or Height of the Canvas won't have much effect on its children.